# My Array item keeps getting overwritten in C programming

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that allows users to add information into a nameCard array using a function called AddNameCard. but when I try to add another set of input in, the previous items seems to get overwritten. and the listnamecard function only displays the last inputted items. Anyone know what i need to do to get around this problem? I'm learning C programming currently, go easy on me please :).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# define Max_Size 5

typedef struct
{
  int nameCardID;
  char personName[20];
  char companyName[20];

} NameCard;

NameCard nameCard[Max_Size];

void AddNameCard() {
  int j;
  printf("\n");
  for (int i = j - 1; i < j; i++){

      printf("Enter Name Card ID: \n");
      scanf("%d", &nameCard[i].nameCardID);

      printf("Enter Person Name: \n");
      scanf("%s", &nameCard[i].personName);

      printf("Enter Company Name : \n");
      scanf("%s", &nameCard[i].companyName);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return;
}

void ListNameCard() {
  int j;

  printf("\n");
  printf("\nName_Card_ID Person_Name Company_Name \n");

  for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
       printf("%d %s %s \n", nameCard[i].nameCardID, nameCard[i].personName, nameCard[i].companyName);
  }
 printf("\n");
 return;
}

void GetNameCard() {
 printf("%d %s %s", nameCard[1].nameCardID, nameCard[1].personName, nameCard[1].companyName);
}

int main()
{
  int options;

  while (options != 5) {

  printf("1:List Name Cards\n2:Add Name Card\n3:Remove Name Cards\n4:Get Name Cards\n5:quit\n");
  printf("\n");

  printf("What would you like to do? : ");
  scanf("%d", &options);

  switch (options)
  {
    case 1:
        ListNameCard();
        break;
    case 2:
        AddNameCard();
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Case3 ");
        printf("\n");
        break;
    case 4:
        GetNameCard();
        break;
    default:
        printf("quit ");
  }

 }
```

Comment: You're not initializing `j` variable.

Comment: likewise with `options`. In C, variable declarations don't take on default values, you have to initialize them to something. For instance `int options = 5;`. Without that, the value of `options` (in this example) is indeterminate. In this case you need to `scanf("%d", &options);` before checking its value with `while (options != 5) {`

Comment: also, `scanf("%s", &nameCard[i].personName);` --> `scanf("%s", nameCard[i].personName);` (drop the `&`) and the same for `.companyName`. When you pass the name of an array in this context, it decays to a pointer to the first element that it points to, a `char*`, which is what `scanf("%s")` wants. [Turn on your warnings and fix them](https://godbolt.org/z/bEj9Ef3Eo)

Comment: j needs to be a global variable!

Comment: A global variable is almost never the right answer. Presumably `j` is meant to be the number of cards currently added. This information can be tracked in `main` and passed as an argument to each of the functions. Alternatively, a `NameCardDeck` struct could be defined which keeps track internally of the number of cards currently stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define Max_Size 5

typedef struct {
        int nameCardID;
        char personName[20];
        char companyName[20];

}
NameCard;

NameCard nameCard[Max_Size];

void AddNameCard() {
        printf("\n");
        int i;
        printf("enter the number of person you want to add :");
        scanf("%d", & i);
        printf("Enter Name Card ID: \n");
        scanf("%d", & nameCard[i - 1].nameCardID);
        printf("Enter Person Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", nameCard[i - 1].personName);
        printf("Enter Company Name : \n");
        scanf("%s", nameCard[i - 1].companyName);
        printf("\n");
        return;
}

void ListNameCard() {
        printf("\n");
        printf("\nName_Card_ID Person_Name Company_Name \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Max_Size; i++) {
                printf("%d %s %s \n", nameCard[i].nameCardID, nameCard[i].personName, nameCard[i].companyName);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
}

void GetNameCard() {
        int n;
        printf("\n");
        printf("enter the number of the person");
        scanf("%d", & n);
        printf("%d %s %s", nameCard[n - 1].nameCardID, nameCard[n - 1].personName, nameCard[n - 1].companyName);
        printf("\n");
}
int main() {
        int options;

        while (options != 5) {

                printf("1:List Name Cards\n2:Add Name Card\n3:Remove Name Cards\n4:Get Name Cards\n5:quit\n");
                printf("\n");
                printf("What would you like to do? : ");
                scanf("%d", & options);

                switch (options) {
                case 1:
                        ListNameCard();
                        break;
                case 2:
                        AddNameCard();
                        break;
                case 3:
                        printf("Case3 ");
                        printf("\n");
                        break;
                case 4:
                        GetNameCard();
                        break;
                default:
                        printf("quit ");
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what changes were made?

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the comments' suggestions.

First we avoid using `options` variable uninitialized by changing:

```
while (options != 5) {
    ...
}
```

To:

```
do {

    ... (set options variable here)

} while (options != 5);
```

Secondly, we change the name of `j` variable to `count` and use it as function parameter/return so we keep track and update the number of added cards. For instance, `AddNameCard` becomes:

```
int AddNameCard(int count)
{   
  if (count < Max_Size) {

    count++;

    int i = count - 1;

    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Name Card ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &nameCard[i].nameCardID);
    discard_newline();

    printf("Enter Person Name: ");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", nameCard[i].personName);
    discard_newline();

    printf("Enter Company Name: ");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", nameCard[i].companyName);
    discard_newline();

  } else {

    printf("Maximum number of cards reached\n");
  }   

  printf("\n");

  return count;
}
```

(`discard_newline` prevents newline characters to creep into the next `scanf`. `"%19[^\n]"` format prevents buffer overrun into `20` length strings.)
The name of an array variable is already taken as its address (or the address of its first element). So `personName` and `companyName` members shouldn't be preceded by `&`.

The code becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Max_Size 5

typedef struct
{
  int nameCardID;
  char personName[20];
  char companyName[20];

} NameCard;

NameCard nameCard[Max_Size];

void discard_newline(void)
{
  while( getchar() != '\n' );
}

int AddNameCard(int count)
{
  if (count < Max_Size) {

    count++;

    int i = count - 1;

    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter Name Card ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &nameCard[i].nameCardID);
    discard_newline();

    printf("Enter Person Name: ");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", nameCard[i].personName);
    discard_newline();

    printf("Enter Company Name: ");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", nameCard[i].companyName);
    discard_newline();

  } else {

    printf("Maximum number of cards reached\n");
  }

  printf("\n");

  return count;
}

void ListNameCard(int count) {

  if (count > 0) {

    printf("\nName_Card_ID Person_Name Company_Name\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
         printf("%d %s %s \n", nameCard[i].nameCardID, nameCard[i].personName, nameCard[i].companyName);
    }

  } else {

    printf("Empty list: none added yet\n");
  }

  printf("\n");

   return;
}

void GetNameCard() {
 printf("%d %s %s", nameCard[1].nameCardID, nameCard[1].personName, nameCard[1].companyName);
}

int main()
{
  int options;
  int count = 0;

  do {

    printf("1:List Name Cards\n2:Add Name Card\n3:Remove Name Cards\n4:Get Name Cards\n5:quit\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("What would you like to do? : ");
    scanf("%d", &options);

    switch (options)
    {
      case 1:
          ListNameCard(count);
          break;
      case 2:
          count = AddNameCard(count);
          break;
      case 3:
          printf("Case3 ");
          printf("\n");
          break;
      case 4:
          GetNameCard();
          break;
      default:
          printf("quit\n");
    }

  } while (options != 5);
}
```

Running it:

```
1:List Name Cards
2:Add Name Card
3:Remove Name Cards
4:Get Name Cards
5:quit

What would you like to do? : 1 
Empty list: none added yet 

1:List Name Cards
2:Add Name Card
3:Remove Name Cards
4:Get Name Cards
5:quit

What would you like to do? : 2 

Enter Name Card ID: 123 
Enter Person Name: John Smith
Enter Company Name: COMP_01

1:List Name Cards
2:Add Name Card
3:Remove Name Cards
4:Get Name Cards
5:quit

What would you like to do? : 1 

Name_Card_ID Person_Name Company_Name
123 John Smith COMP_01 

1:List Name Cards
2:Add Name Card
3:Remove Name Cards
4:Get Name Cards
5:quit

What would you like to do? : 5 
quit
```

You still have to complete the other options.